# How to find the values of x and y in equations like ax+by=c?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

for example this equation: 505x-673y=1 . x=4 and y = 3. but how can I find them with mathematics. What would be the approach here?

Comment: This equation has infinite many solutions.

Comment: so how can I find them?

Comment: thanks @JeanMarie

Comment: If you rearrange, you can get a simple first order equation. $y=\frac{c}{b}-\frac{a}{b}x$ , so if you plug in any value for x you will get a solution for y.

Comment: I just transformed my previous comment into a slightly expanded answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a simply diophantine equation. To solve this, you have basically to express $673$ in terms of $505$ and $1$ using euclid algorithm. The result, as you have shown is $x=4$ and $y=3$ because:
$$505\cdot4-673\cdot3=1$$

Comment: I don't know what that but I will search about it now, thanks for showing me the way

Comment: @Moswers: if this answer has been useful, maybe a $+1$ or a favourite answer?

Answer (score 0):

This was a comment, but I think deserves to be an answer.

As your question is asking for a method, here it is.

- 1) First, divide by the common factor $d=GCD(a,b,c)$.
- 2) Then apply "extended Euclidean algorithm" which will give you  coefficients $x',y'$ called "Bezout coefficients".
- 3) The final coefficients are : $x'=dx, y'=dy$.

See the details of point 2) here.

Comment: merci beaucoup, I just watched a video about Bezout coefficients and understood everything.